# Sign table in $2^k$ factorial experiment

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I have a factorial experiment with four factors $\{A,B,C,D\}$ ($k=4$) , just to ilustrate the case with $k=3$, the signal table is

\begin{matrix}
& I & A & B & C & AB & AC & BC & ABC\\
(1) & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1\\
a & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1\\
b & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1\\
ab & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
c & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1\\
ac & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1\\
bc & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1\\
abc & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1\\
\end{matrix}

I know this is just a signal table with produtcts of $+ $and $-$, but is there any quick way to assemble it without having to look at the signs?

I would like to know it, because with the table is easier and faster to calculate the contrasts, otherwise I would have to do

$$A=(a-1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$$
$$B=(a+1)(b-1)(c+1)(d+1)$$
$$.....$$
$$ABCD=(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)$$

Is there any easier way to assemble this table?

As I need to make the table a hand to study for the exam, I was looking at it and I saw a few things about the contrasts

$(A,B,C,D)$: $+1$ in which the letter appears

$(AB,AC,BC,AD,BD,CD)$: $+1$ in $(1)$, in the rows where the pair appears and in the rows where one or two of the letters does not belong to the pair appears

$(ABC,ABD,ACD,BCD)$:$+1$ in rows which appears each letter of triple alone, row in which the triple appears and rows where the letter does not belong to triple appears (only in pairs)

$ABCD$: $+1$ in all pairs and $ABCD$

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by isolating the basis:
$$\begin{array} {r|r|rrr|rrrr}
& I & A & B & C & AB & AC & BC & ABC\\
(1) & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1\\
a & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1\\
b & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1\\
ab & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
c & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1\\
ac & +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1\\
bc & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1\\
abc & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1\\
\end{array}$$
Columns $A,B,C$ are just counting in binary, but if you reordered the rows then they're still simple: $A$ is $+1$ iff $a$ is in the row label; etc.

Column $AB$ is just column $A$ pointwise multiplied by column $B$; similarly column $ABC$ is just column $AB$ pointwise multiplied by column $C$; so no cell in the table requires more than one multiplication.

The result is that it's a question of parity. For even-length column labels ($I$ counts as even because it's really a substitute for the empty string) you get $+1$ in rows where an even number of the letters occur (e.g. $ABCD$ is even, so it will be $+1$ in rows $(1)$, $ab$, $ac$, $ad$, $bc$, $bd$, $cd$, $abcd$); for odd-length column labels you get $+1$ in rows where an odd number of the letters occur (e.g. $ABC$ is odd, so it will be $+1$ in rows $a$, $b$, $c$, $ad$, $bd$, $cd$, $abc$, $abcd$).

Really there's no reason to prepare a table like this by hand. Whatever software you're using for the analysis can probably do it for you, but as an online option [this program](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2q~%23%3AF%2C%7B2bW%25ee%7B~'A%40%2B*%7D%25M*%22I%22e%7C%7D%25Ma%5C%2B'%2C*N%0AF%2C%7B%0A%20%20R2bW%25ee%7B~'a%40%2B*%7D%25M*%22(1)%22e%7C'%2C%0A%20%20F%2C%7BR~%262b%3A%5E%22%2B-%22%3D'1%2B%7D%25'%2C*%0A%20%20N%0A%7DfR&input=3) will generate a CSV file of the table. Just change the input value and press Run.

Comment: But the problem is when I have four factors $A,B,C,D$

Comment: Ok, which specific part do you have trouble generalising to the four-factor case?

Comment: For $A,B,C,D$ is just put $+1$ in the row that letter appear, but for the cases $AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD$ and $ABC,ABD,ACD,BCD$ and $ABCD$ I could not see any pattern, and look at the signs takes too long